# How to get data from Edit Text in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview with edit text. Each row has a edit text. I am entering values in the edit text manually and after i enter values, I want to get those values in each and every row. I want to get those values to the main activity. There may be 10 to 20 rows in the recyclerview. I want to get all values in those edit texts.

This is my Adapter

```
public class SelectItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private List<String> itemsName, itemsQty, itemsPCode, itemPlant;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public SelectItemAdapter(Context context, String[] mDataset) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        itemsName = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsQty = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsPCode = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemPlant = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.mDataset = mDataset;


    }


    @Override
    public SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_selected_item, parent, false);
        return new ItemHolder(itemView, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));
        holder.setItemQty(itemsQty.get(position));
        holder.setItemPCode(itemsPCode.get(position));
        holder.setItemPlant(itemPlant.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsName.size();
    }

    public Object getItemName(int position) {
        return itemsName.get(position);
    }

    public Object getItemPCode(int position) {
        return itemsPCode.get(position);
    }

    public Object getItemPlant(int position) {
        return itemPlant.get(position);
    }


    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        onItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
        return onItemClickListener;
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);
    }

    public void add(int location, String iName, String iQty, String iPCode, String iPlant) {
        itemsName.add(location, iName);
        itemsQty.add(location, iQty);
        itemsPCode.add(location, iPCode);
        itemPlant.add(location, iPlant);
        notifyItemInserted(location);
    }

    public void remove(int location) {
        if (location >= itemsName.size())
            return;

        itemsName.remove(location);
        notifyItemRemoved(location);
    }

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private SelectItemAdapter parent;
        TextView textItemName, txtPCode, txtAvailableQty, txtTempQty, txtPlant;
        Button bRemove;
        EditText numPicker;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView, SelectItemAdapter parent) {
            super(itemView);
            this.parent = parent;
            textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProductName);
            txtAvailableQty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAvailbleQty);
            txtPCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPCode);
            txtPlant = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPlant);
            bRemove = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bRemove);
            numPicker = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
            bRemove.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setItemName(CharSequence name) {
            textItemName.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemQty(CharSequence name) {
            txtAvailableQty.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemPCode(CharSequence name) {
            txtPCode.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemPlant(CharSequence name) {
            txtPlant.setText(name);
        }

        public String getQtyNumber() {
            return numPicker.getText().toString();
        }

        public CharSequence getItemName() {
            return textItemName.getText();
        }


        public CharSequence getItemPCode() {
            return txtPCode.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is how i tried to get values. But it is not working

```
private String getNumPicNumber(int i) {
        if (myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i) instanceof SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder) {
            SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder childHolder = (SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder) myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);
            numberPickerNumber = childHolder.getQtyNumber();
        }
        return numberPickerNumber;
    }
```

Comment: How you handle the focus on Edit text in RecyclerView? Doesn't it lose focus on scroll.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to use so many lists, just create a class that will contain all the data of single item, there is no need for buttons, use just text change listener instead.

sample code

```
public class RetItem
{
    public String _itemName;
    public String _itemQty;
    public String _itemPcode;
    public String _itemPlant;
}

public class SelectItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private List<RetItem> _retData;
     public SelectItemAdapter(Context context, String[] mDataset) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        _retData = new ArrayList<RetItem>(mDataset.length);
        this.mDataset = mDataset;
    }

      @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));
        holder.setItemName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
             int count, int after) {
           }

           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             _retData.get(position)._itemName = s.toString();
           }
          });

        holder.setItemQty(itemsQty.get(position));
        holder.setItemQty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
             int count, int after) {
           }

           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             _retData.get(position)._itemQty = s.toString();
           }
          });

        holder.setItemPCode(itemsPCode.get(position));
        holder.setItemPCode.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
             int count, int after) {
           }

           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             _retData.get(position)._itemPcode = s.toString();
           }
          });       
        holder.setItemPlant(itemPlant.get(position));
        holder.setItemPlant.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
             int count, int after) {
           }

           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             _retData.get(position)._itemPlant = s.toString();
           }
          });
    }

    public List<RetItem> retrieveData()
    {
        return _retData;
    }
}
```

Comment: while using addTextChangedListener on each of the editTexts, the text will be in s CharSequence, this text will be saved in _retData structure as you can see. when you want to get the data from the adapter just call retrieveData function

Comment: no they are not edit text. Those you put addTextChangedListener, they are text view. **numPicker ** is the edit text.

Comment: so instead of  holder.setItemQty.addTextChangedListener just do  holder.numPicker.addTextChangedListener

Comment: thank you for the response. this helped me to go for a solution. so i accept this answer

Comment: Thank you ,but for this to work we have to make few changes .
_retData = new ArrayList<RetItem>(mDataset.length); // this doesnt initialse the retData array with an initial size , It only sets a maximum size for the array. An this will give an array index out of bounds exception
So this is what we have to do
_retData = new ArrayList<RetItem>(mData.size());
        for (int i =0;i<mData.size();++i){
            _retData.add(new RetItem("",""));
        }

Answer (score 2):

To do this there are two ways:-

1) Add save Button in each row of RecyclerView
  on this Button click (onClick)

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           String ans = holher.numPicker.getText().toString();
           // save ans to sharedpreferences or Database
        }
```

2) Add onTextChangedListener to EditText

```
holher.mumPicker.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      String ans = holher.numPicker.getText().toString();
           // save ans to sharedpreferences or Database
   }
  });
```

Then in your **MainActivity.java** retrive data from sharedpreferences or database

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.My Recyclerview contained one Textview, two EditTexts and one remove Button to remove the item from the Recyclerview. I am getting the data from both the Edittexts, from a model class using a button from my activity. Everything works well I just want to know what all optimizations I can make. Please give your suggestions in a detailed manner.

My Model Class:

```
public class OrderGS {
  String names, rty,qty;

    public OrderGS(String name, String rty, String qty) {
        this.names = name;
        this.rty = rty;
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return names;
    }

    public void setName(String names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    public String getRty() {
        return rty;
    }

    public void setRty(String rty) {
        this.rty = rty;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }
}
```

Above class holds the three Strings one is the titile and the two hold the edittext data.

My Adapter code:

```
class OOHolderI extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView title;
        EditText rty,qty;
        public OOHolderI(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_order);
            rty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editRTY);
            qty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editQTY);
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_remove).setOnClickListener(v -> {
               arrayList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
               if(rtyArray.size()>0) {
                   rtyArray.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                   qtyArray.remove(getAdapterPosition());
               }
               notifyDataSetChanged();
           });
            rty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                arrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setRty(s.toString());
                if(!rtyArray.contains(getAdapterPosition())){
                rtyArray.add(getAdapterPosition());}
                }
            });
            qty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    arrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setQty(s.toString());
                    if(!qtyArray.contains(getAdapterPosition())) {
                        qtyArray.add(getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }

            });


        }

}
```

In the adapter I am using two arraylists `rtyArray` and `qtyArray` to hold the position of the Edittext data in the model class.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getRTY() {
    return rtyArray;
}
public ArrayList<Integer> getQTY(){
    return qtyArray;
}
```

The above two functions return the positions of the Edittextdata

My Activity:

```
 findViewById(R.id.button_save).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            ArrayList<Integer> rtyArray = adapter.getRTY();
            ArrayList<Integer> qtyArray = adapter.getQTY();
            if(rtyArray.size()>0) {
               for(Integer i: rtyArray){
              //get data here like 
              arrayListOfModel.get(i).getRty(); 
              arrayListOfModel.get(qtyArray.get(i)).getQty();
               }
            }
        });
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In my case both the position holding arrays are always equal in size.

Answer (score 0):

To get text of clicked TextField in RecyclerView, in ViewHolder you can get text of clicked textfield.

```
   public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView myData;
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myData = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked " + myData.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
            }
        });
    }
}
```