# Groupview with Edittext in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview

I have created an ExpandableListView with an EditText in a GroupView.
Is there someone who knows how to save(maintain) the EditText values of the GroupView?.

Comment: Basically there are may answers already for this question, you need to add a data structure that will contain all the strings of one item, then you will need to add addTextChangedListener to the edittext and on onTextChanged you will need to save the string in the data structure 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096547/how-to-get-data-from-edit-text-in-a-recyclerview/37097190#37097190

Comment: @visionixvisionix i am asking expandable listview groupview(Parent) with edittext

Answer (score 0):

It the same principle

```
//you need to allocate the data structure in size of the amount of items in your list
List<String> _retData = new ArrayList<String>(_data.size());
```

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    Holder h = null; //this will hold the edittext instances of eachItem in expand list
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(_context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2,
                parent, false);
        h = new Holder();
        h._editText = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        convertView.setTag(h);
    }
    else
    {
        h = (Holder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    //saving the data when the user write something... 
    h._editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int count, int after) {
       }

       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
         _retData.get(groupPosition)._itemPlant = s.toString();
       }
      });
```

}

you can see in more details the post in my comment above

Comment: Hi "_retData.get(groupPosition)._itemPlant = s.toString();" may u know the line description. And also once saved edittext details .while click on groupwise old values are missing .

Comment: when you change the text on the editText a callback is fired onTextChanged only when the user change the text you will need to save it in _resData structure according to groupPosition of the item, do you delete the values when the groupItem is closed?

Comment: It will be more helpful if you could describe what do not work properly
whats working for now?

Comment: now working fine . i got the solution .Thanks for your support